# Idiomatic way to construct a default value for a dictionary key in swift and set it

Tags: swift, swift4, foundation

I'm looking for the idiomatic swifty way to create and then set values for collections contained in a dictionary for non existing keys

My code is quite tedious with this type of code scattered around:

```
var myDict = Dictionary<String,Array<String>>()
var arr = myDict["key"]
if arr = nil {
  arr = Array<String>()
  myDict["key"] = arr
}

... do something with arr...
```

is there something that handles this?

Comment: Why not just use nil coalescing like this: `var array: [String] = myDict["key"] ?? []` ?

Comment: Never mind - you want to also set the dict's value to the default one...

Comment: I wanted to set the default value for that key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to set a default value for a `Dictionary`, but you can specify a `default` value when looking up a dictionary value:

```
var arr = myDict["key", default: []]
```

`default` provides a default value if the key is not found.  In this case, you can use `[]` which Swift will infer to be an empty array of type `[String]`.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I assume it will also set that value for the key correct?

Comment: It doesn't change the dictionary.  It just provides a default value if one isn't there.  To update the dictionary, you'd have to do something like: `myDict["key"] = myDict["key", default: []]`.

Comment: This comes in handy for counting words for instance with a `[String : Int]` array.  You can do: `var counts = [String : Int](); 
counts["hello", default: 0] += 1` and `counts["hello"]` will be set to `1`.

Comment: I tried doing this but got some compilation errors when trying to call it

```extension Dictionary {
  subscript(k: Key, defaultValue: Value) -> Value {
    mutating get {
      let it = self[k]
      if it == nil {
        self[k] = defaultValue
        return defaultValue
      }
      return it!
    }
  }
}```

Comment: besides the compilation errors, I'm also having another issue when I set the collection for that key. It is copied and not "by reference" so I can't set values in the inner collection. for instance here:

```var mySet = myDict[ke, default: []]
    if mySet.count == 0 {
      myDict[key] = mySet
    }
    mySet.insert(item)```

Comment: Right, because dict is a value type and `mySet` is a copy.  You have to write it back after you modify it.